# Sqlalchemy: UPDATE... LIMIT 1, not possible?

Tags: sqlalchemy

In MySQL it is possible to limit the number of records affected by an update query. In an ideal world this should not be necessary, but having such a limit does in some cases help save your bacon :)

I'd have thought that in SQLAlchemy it can be achieved by something like:

```
tgt_meta.tables['ps_product'].update(tgt_meta.tables['ps_product'].c.id_product == product_id).values(**upd_product_values).limit(1)
```

But apparently this is not so.

```
AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'limit'
```

Is there something else that I can try?

Answer (score 4):

The Mysql dialect has this thrown in as `update(..., mysql_limit=x)`

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#mysql-sql-extensions