# UPDATE .. LIMIT 1 with SqlAlchemy and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-update, sql-limit

With SqlAlchemy, is it possible to build a query which will update only the first matching row?

In my case, I need to update the most recent log entry:

```
class Log(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'logs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    #...
    analyzed = Column(Boolean)

session.query(Log)  \
    .order_by(Log.id.desc())  \
    .limit(1)  \
    .update({ 'analyzed': True })
```

Which results into:

> InvalidRequestError: Can't call Query.update() when limit() has been called

It makes sense, since `UPDATE ... LIMIT 1` is a MySQL-only feature (with the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13597779/134904))

But how would I do the same with PostgreSQL? Possibly, using [the subquery approach](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497)?

Comment: The best solution depends on whether each concurrent transaction should update ***the same*** first row according to `ORDER BY`, or ***the next*** row, not yet locked,  or a single, random / arbitrary row matching some criteria.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [subquery recipe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497) is the right way to do it, now we only need to build this query with SqlAlchemy.

Let's start with the subquery:

```
sq = ssn.query(Log.id)  \
    .order_by(Log.id.desc())  \
    .limit(1)  \
    .with_for_update()
```

And now use it with [as_scalar()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.as_scalar) 
with the example from the [update() docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update.params.whereclause):

```
from sqlalchemy import update

q = update(Log)  \
    .values({'analyzed': True})  \
    .where(Log.id == sq.as_scalar())
```

Print the query to have a look at the result:

```
UPDATE logs 
SET analyzed=:analyzed 
WHERE logs.id = (
    SELECT logs.id 
    FROM logs ORDER BY logs.id DESC 
    LIMIT :param_1 
    FOR UPDATE
)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: ... and if you're trying to use it for queuing, keep concurrency in mind. It's not atomic, so multiple sessions can grab and update the same row.

Comment: That's a little unfortunate because a subquery isn't directly needed in plenty of RDBM's. Is there a way to force SQLAlchemy to limit an update?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the same row from being updated multiple times, add:

```
WHERE analyzed <> :analyzed
```

Or if `NULL` values are allowed:

```
WHERE analyzed IS DISTINCT FROM :analyzed
```

Add the same condition to the outer `UPDATE` as well, which is almost always a good idea in any case to [avoid empty updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860).

Concurrent transactions being blocked by the `ROW SHARE` lock from `FOR UPDATE` wake up as soon as the first transaction finishes. Since the changed row does not pass the `WHERE` condition any more, the subquery returns no row and *nothing* happens.

While later transactions lock a new row to update ...

You could use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS) to always update the next unlocked row without waiting. More details here:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)

There is also the related [PGQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PGQ_Tutorial) to implement queues. (Never used it myself).

Answer (score 1):

my DB won't work with limit inside subquery - so I ended up using something like this:

```
log_id = session.query(Log.id)  \
    .order_by(Log.id.desc())  \
    .limit(1)
log_id = [log.id for log in log_id]
session.query(Log).filter(Log.id.in_(log_id)).delete()
```