# Flask sqlalchemy update limit

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, limit, flask-sqlalchemy

I try to execute update query with limit in Flask, using Flask-SQLAlchemy (not SQLAlchemy!).

```
db.session.query(ItemObject).filter_by(owner_type=0,item_id=item_id.decode('hex')).update({'owner_type': '1'})
```

When i try ".limit(1)" or "update({'owner_type': '1'}, mysql_limit=1)" i geting error

```
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'limit'
```

or

```
TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mysql_limit'
```

How can i make this query without using execute()?

Answer (score 0):

For your first error, it sounds like you're trying to call limit() after calling update().

```
db.session.query(ItemObject).filter_by(owner_type=0,item_id=item_id.decode('hex')).update({'owner_type': '1'})
```

This line returns a `long` because `update()` returns the number of rows that were matched (not modified!). You can't chain a limit after an update.

You *also* can't call `limit` on a query with `update`, so it wouldn't work anyways. That's just a MySQL thing.

Take a look at this previous answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25943713/175320 - which shows you how to get the same end result but in a portable manner using subqueries.

Comment: "That's just a MySQL thing."
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html